# Mapping two tables (many to many relationship) in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to join 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281891/how-to-join-2-tables)

I am very new to databases. I am trying two link to tables together, using a third map table. How do I go about doing this in oracle?
Thank you.

Comment: This should have been googled, not posted. It's unacceptable to not bother doing basic research before posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming two tables `A` and `B` that have `ID`s of type `INT`...

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  ID INT,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE B (
  ID INT,
  ...
)
```

You would map them with:

```
CREATE TABLE ABCrossReference (
  A_ID INT,
  B_ID INT
)
```

And store `A.ID` in `ABCrossReference.A_ID` and `B.ID` in `ABCrossReference.B_ID`

Finally you would `JOIN` them together to get the data:

```
SELECT * FROM A
JOIN ABCrossReference ON A.ID = ABCrossReference.A_ID
JOIN B ON ABCrossReference.B_ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn about JOIN feature. You can read more about it here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp